# 401 Unauthorized SVN - Login Repository

Tags: apache, authentication, svn

I can't login repository. 
My access file (svn-acl):

```
[/]
adminsvn = r

[HRMS:/]
vietnh = rw
```

My auth file (svn-auth-file):

```
adminsvn:0LGs..FO01CMY
quanldm:$1$O8gvAKWF$Jp.8O1jO3yKDMD75bBF9V.
vietnh:$1$0rk/S.gb$egIzv3RuDzxEA3yRS4Yb3/
```

My httpd.conf:

```
<Location /Repositories>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath D:\Apps\SVN\Repositories

    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile D:/Apps/SVN/Config/svn-auth-file
    AuthzSVNAccessFile D:/Apps/SVN/Config/svn-acl

    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Enter the URL: http://localhost:8080/Repositories/HRMS 
Fill username: vietnh and password: 123
And get the response:
**401 Unauthorized**

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
Error log file: 
AH01617: user vietnh: authentication failure for "/Repositories/HRMS": Password Mismatch 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Password Mismatch", as written - you entered incorrect password

Comment: I entered correct password multiple times but it's still not working, someone said this issuse turned out to be a pound sign (£) in the users password. Right?

Comment: Out of ideas... but you can try to change password in passwd-file for test

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Cause is Create User function generate password wrong. It's not generate "MD5 password hash". Solution is force it generate MD5 type.