# How to Reload Data jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and I have a problem with refresh data after call event of jstree. 
I'm following in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772334/how-to-get-jqgrid-reload-to-go-to-server). Exactly I don't know where to put it. 
This is my code. What shoud I do?

```
$('#jsTree_DonVi').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var id = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).id;
    var text = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).text;
    var tinhTrang = 0;
    var nam = 0;

    // I tried but it's not working 
    $("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
    $("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
    //---

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/GetData',
        postData: {
            "id": id,
            "nam": nam,
            "tinhTrang": tinhTrang
        },
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
           {
               label: 'Tên công trình', name: 'Ten', sorttype: 'string', width: 800, align: 'center'
           },
           { label: 'Kế hoạch/Thực hiện', name: 'KHTH', sorttype: 'string', align: 'center' },
           { label: 'Địa điểm xây dựng', name: 'DiaDiem', sorttype: 'string', align: 'center' }
        ],
        viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
        rowNum: 30,
        width: 1228,
        height: 500,
        loadonce: true,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    })};
```

My HTML:

```html
<div id="renderTable">
    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution here**: 
I changed my jqGrid from [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102663) to [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). 
And replace

```
$("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
$("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

To

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

Comment: Could you post you HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the problem exist because you create the grid inside of event handler (`$('#jsTree_DonVi').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {/* here */});`. It's important to understand that jqGrid converts initial empty `<table id="jqGrid"></table>` in relatively complex structure of tables and divs. See [the post](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid) for more details.

You can fix the problem by usage of `GridUnload` method for example. You can replace the lines

```
$("#jqGrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
$("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

with the line

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid("GridUnload");
```

The implementation of `GridUnload` can depend on the fork of jqGrid, which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop the fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I would recommend you. You can use it from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) or to install from one from well-known JavaScript repositories: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid) or [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org/) (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md)).

Comment: Exaclty what I need. Thank you so much. You saved my life.

Comment: @QuanLeDucMinh: By the way, it's recommended that you "accept" the answers which your wrote yourself on your questions (see [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34014810/315935)). It gives searching engine the tip that the information from the answer is *helpful* and it *solves* the problem.